# Trig/Precalculus help! Airplane bearing and distance from mountain

Tags: trigonometry

A plane flying a straight course observes a mountain at a bearing of 35.1degrees to the right of its course. At that time the plane is 9 kilometers from the mountain. A short time​ later, the bearing to the mountain becomes 45.1degrees. How far is the plane from the mountain when the second bearing is taken​ (to the nearest tenth of a​ km)?

I'm unsure of how to make a drawing of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the diagram below, $I$ is the point where the initial bearing is taken, $N$ is the point where the new bearing is taken, and $M$ is the position of the mountain.  The arrow indicates the direction of the plane.  Note that the angles measure the direction to the mountain relative to the course of the plane.

[image: airplane_bearings_to_the_mountain]

Your task is to use the given information to find $|NM|$, the distance from the point where the second bearing is taken to the mountain.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Draw a ray $OA$ of length $9$ and angle $35.1^\circ$  Then draw another ray $AB$ with new angle $45.1 ^\circ$.  Then you will have ray $OB$ that will indicate the distance with the new bearing.  Your job will then be to find the other angles and the actual distance.

Comment: Thanks for catching this...I've edited my post above.

Comment: In your new formulation, the mountain is at $O$, the first bearing is taken at $A$, and the second bearing is taken at $B$, so we want to find $OB$, the distance between the point where the second bearing is taken and the mountain.

Comment: Can you tell I've been out of the geometry business for awhile (or I hadn't had my breakfast?) XD  You have a better explanation and a better answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that angle MNI is $180-45.1=134.9$ degrees. So using law of cuisines on triangle MNI we get
$(\sin 134.9)/9=(\sin 35.1)/x$. We can approximate the angles as $135$ and $35$ and using the sine addition formula to find that $x$ is approximately $9\sqrt{2}\sin 35$ which is about $7.3$.